# XML PARSING using XPath Expression

Tags: java, xml-parsing, xquery

I have to parse a XML document using XQUERY. The XPATh expression is :

```
(fn:node-name(.) eq fn:QName(#namespace,#name))
```

where `#namespace` is the namespace for the `QName` specified as the content of the `<cf:qname>` element and `#name` is the local name for the `QName`

Please tell me how to get the node data?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If the namespace URI and node name are statically known, you can just use

```
declare namespace ns='#namespace';
//ns:#name
```

Otherwise you select all nodes and test for the name with an XPath predicate:

```
//*[fn:node-name(.) eq fn:QName(#namespace,#name)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
declare namespace cf="cf";

let $xml :=
  <x:ml xmlns:x="x"><x:yz/></x:ml>
let $cfqname :=
  <cf:qname><cf:namespace-uri>x</cf:namespace-uri><cf:local-name>yz</cf:local-name></cf:qname>
let $qname :=
  fn:QName($cfqname/cf:namespace-uri, $cfqname/cf:local-name)
return
  $xml//*[node-name(.) eq $qname]
```